# IBM MQ9 channel creation with name SYSYTEM.DEF.SVRCONN

Tags: ibm-server

I am getting the below error while trying to create channel with name `SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN` in IBM MQ9.

```
DEFINE CHANNEL (system.def.svrconn) CHLTYPE (SVRCONN)
     8 : DEFINE CHANNEL (system.def.svrconn) CHLTYPE (SVRCONN)
AMQ8150E: IBM MQ object already exists.
```

Any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

The error means what it says.   By default the channel `SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN` exists on all IBM MQ queue managers.  The purpose of this specific channel is to provide the default properties to use when new `SVRCONN` channels are defined.

Despite many examples showing this channel name, it should not be used and is disabled by a default `CHLAUTH` rule.